# Linking runtime library for test with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, ctest

Is there any simple way to link at runtime a locally built library to a test with CMAKE?

For example:

```
enable_testing()
add_executable(Test test/Test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test -L../lib/libzmq/build/lib/ zmq)
add_test(
  NAME TestClientZmq
  COMMAND "LD_PRELOAD=../lib/libzmq/build/lib/libzmq.so Test")
```

Running the test will complain about the missing library at runtime:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libzmq.so.4.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can either:

1. Set `LD_PRELOAD` when running ctest
2. Write a wrapper script which does this and then calls the executable (what I have currently)

I would prefer to do everything in cmake though, since I think it's best to keep all this configuration in a single place to avoid bugs in the future.

Comment: Did you try to set the linker option [`-Wl,-rpath=...`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

to your  `CMakeLists.txt`. As explained in this [wiki article](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).

After build, use the below command to make sure the RPATH is properly set:

```
objdump -x Test | grep RPATH
```